# Get absolute image's path in DRF

Tags: python, image, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm recently approaching drf and I want to create a system that returns a user's information. Among the various fields, the user has an avatar which should return the URL of the photo where it is saved. The problem is that I get a relative path instead of an absolute path. Below I attach the code of my app.

models.py

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('images' , 'avatar' , str(instance.pk),filename)
    
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True, null=True,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

serializers.py

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id','username','email','name','surname','avatar',]
```

views.py

```
class CustomUserAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

what I get is this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Test",
    "avatar": "/media/images/avatar/1/photo.JPG"
}
```

but what I need to get is this

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Test",
        "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/avatar/1/photo.JPG"
}
```

how can I solve it? Thanks in advance for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) attribute available on FileFields (which ImageFields also are); you can get at it neatly with [`field.source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source).

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.CharField(source="avatar.url")

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            "id",
            "username",
            "email",
            "name",
            "surname",
            "avatar",
        ]
```

Comment: in this way even the login that is in another function, which returns the avatar in the correct way, starts returning the relative path instead of the absolute one... so strange

Answer (score 0):

Set the [**`UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL`** setting <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#settings) to `True`:

```
# settings.py

# …

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL': True,
    # …
}
```